# UITextView - Horizontal Scrolling?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextview, horizontal-scrolling

How can I create a **horizontal** scrolling UITextView?

When I set my text programmatically it adds automatic line breaks, so I can only scroll vertically...

```
 titleView.text = @"this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text.";
```

Thanks for your answers.

EDIT: 
So far I tried this:

```
 UIScrollview *yourScrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 ,0 ,       self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
CGFloat textLength = [titleView.text sizeWithFont:titleView.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(9999, 50) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].width;

yourScrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(textLength + 200, 500); //or some value you like, you may have to try this out a few times

titleView.frame = CGRectMake(titleView.frame.origin.x, titleView.frame.origin.y, textLength, titleView.frame.size.height);

[yourScrollview addSubview: titleView];

NSLog(@"%f", textLength);
```

but I received: 'Threat 1: signal SIGABRT'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not yet done something like this, but I would try the following steps to accomplish this:

1. Create a `UIScrollview *yourScrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 ,0 , self.view.frame.size.width, 50)]; //`
2. Use   `CGFloat textLength = [titleView.text sizeWithFont:titleView.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(9999, 50) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].width;`
   to get the final length of your text
3. Set `yourScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(textLength + 20, 50); //or some value you like, you may have to try this out a few times`
4. Also set `titleTextView.frame = CGRectMake(titleTextView.frame.origin.x, titleTextView.frame.origin.y, textLength, titleTextView.frame.size.height);`
5. Make titleView a subview of yourScrollView: `[yourScrollView addSubview: titleView];`

Hope this gives you a good start!

EDIT: This Code will work:

Please notice I used a `UILabel` instead of a `UITextView`.

```
    UILabel *titleView          = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 40)];
    titleView.text              = @"this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text.";
    titleView.font              = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    titleView.backgroundColor   = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleView.numberOfLines     = 1;

    UIScrollView *myScrollView  = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    CGFloat textLength          = [titleView.text sizeWithFont:titleView.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(9999, 50) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].width;
    myScrollView.contentSize    = CGSizeMake(textLength + 20, 50); //or some value you like, you may have to try this out a few times

    titleView.frame             = CGRectMake(titleView.frame.origin.x, titleView.frame.origin.y, textLength, titleView.frame.size.height);

    [myScrollView addSubview: titleView];
    [self.view addSubview:myScrollView];
    [titleView release];
    [myScrollView release];
```

Comment: After adding 'yourScrollView' a subview i get 'Threat 1: signal SIGABRT'

Comment: Please update your question and provide some code so people can see what you have tried so far

Comment: You must have messed up something in your code. I got this working now, see my answer above.

Comment: Tried a whole bunch of stuff with UITextView, had to go with this method finally