# Horizontal Scrolling of textView

Tags: ios, scroll, textview

i need to have the horizontal scrolling enabled on a textView, so i checked this

[image]

but it does not work because in the simulator i got this

[image]

how can i enable it?i've got the textView created in the storyboard and connected in my header like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;
```

is there any delegate to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `contentSize` property of your textview to control the scrollable area.

This is also explained here including code examples: [UITextView - Horizontal Scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190000/uitextview-horizontal-scrolling)

Comment: No you can create the textview in IB, but to adjust the contentSize you'll need some code.

Comment: i tried the link you provided but it doesn't work because it needs to create the TextView programmatically and i don't want that, i created a ScrollView but how can i connect it with my textView?