# Disable line wrapping in editable UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I'm having a stab at creating a code editing app in iOS. `UITextView` seems to be the most appropriate component.

It's all working except that I can't find a way to stop long lines wrapping (so that long lines make the `UITextView` horizontally scrollable).

Is it possible to disable line wrapping in `UITextView`, so that horizontal scrolling is used instead? If so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to let TextView be able to scroll horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407356/how-to-let-textview-be-able-to-scroll-horizontally)

Comment: Not really. That question had a non-editable `UITextView` in mind. The accepted answer is not going to work.