# UITextView Horizontal & Vertical Scroll With Proper Cursor Positioning in Swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uitextview, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

**I am working on a project where I require to make UITextView horizontally scrollable.The problem statement is defined below**

I have tried putting the UITextview within a ScrollView for horizontal scroll as suggested in other similar question solution on Stack Overflow, while the scroll works there are multiple issues related to cursor position like:

- Dynamically setting the width of UITextView to match the width of content's biggest line (achievable)
- Cursor doesn't show on the screen when content increase or decrease i.e while adding content in same line or deleting content in between, cursor position is not handled by UITextView perfectly the cursor jumps to line start and comes back to current position, and is not visible on screen.
- UITextView should only be able to scroll Horizontally or Vertically.(Need to disable the diagonal scroll).

Attaching the current code I am experimenting with, also tried other answers in similar questions, doesn't work.:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scroll:UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var textView:UITextView!

var displayStr = ""
var strSize:CGRect!
var font:UIFont!
var maxSize:CGSize!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    displayStr = textView.text
    textView.delegate = self
    scroll.delegate = self
    scroll.addSubview(textView)
    textView.isEditable = true
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    maxSize = CGSize(width: 9999, height: 9999)
    font = UIFont(name: "Menlo", size: 16)!
    textView.font = font
    updateWidth()
}

func updateWidth() {

    strSize = (displayStr as NSString).boundingRect(with: maxSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : font!], context: nil)

    if strSize.width > self.view.frame.width {
        textView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: strSize.width + 50, height: view.frame.height+10)
    }
    scroll.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: strSize.width + 30, height: strSize.height)
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    updateWidth()
}
```

**This is how my output looks**

[image: This is how my output looks]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to let TextView be able to scroll horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407356/how-to-let-textview-be-able-to-scroll-horizontally)

Comment: There are quite a few other posts, if that one doesn't meet your needs. Just search for `uitextview horizontal scroll`

Comment: Actually, UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView so there is no need to embed one into another, just try to adjust inherited properties.

Comment: you can just adjust the `contentSize` as you see fit

Comment: https://medium.com/@livnoorbrar/the-curious-case-of-uiscrollview-and-uitextview-12aa4a69cd52