# adding ScrollView to my viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

My `label.text` is very huge. I have ensured that my label will contain any amount of text. I just want my view controller to be scrolled so that I can read my label.

I think it's possible with storyboard itself, but I'm not able to do it.

I tried "editor -> embed in -> scroll view". I also tried adding scrollview to my view controller but nothing worked.

Comment: do you want to scroll horizontally or vertically ?

Comment: Then uitextview should do the trick for you :)

Comment: no i just want the entire view controller to be scrollable :) i know textview will help. but i need this

Comment: One way to do it is adjust the frame of the of uitextview to contain the entire text . check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content for furthur help .

Comment: drag a scrollview to the screen, then drag a label as a subview of that scrollview

Answer (score 1):

I see u need to show very long text, then u should use `UITextView`, its basically scrollView for very long text, and can be resize

Comment: no i need the entire view controller to be scrollable.

Comment: Then u might want to check this out [UITextView - Horizontal Scrolling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190000/uitextview-horizontal-scrolling), it basically explain how to make your Label subview of a ScrollView, if thats what u really needs

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can set the label's property numberOfLines is 0.  A Value of 0 means no limit. The text will truncated using the line break  mode.

Comment: do not forget sizeToFit .

Comment: my label is fine.it can accommodate 200 lines or 200 paras as well. the thing is i need to scroll my view controller to see the complete label.text

Comment: I see. why not set your scrollView contentSize according to the text height.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify more for Whole ViewController scrollable means ..

If you add textView then also your view controller is scrollable if you have scroll view in Main view of View Controller.

Nested scroll works very well and scroll whichever scrollview is dragged by user.

And if you want your UILabel scrollable then you need to set ContentSize of scrollView whenever you change Content(text) of UILabel, and don't forget to set Number Of Lines 0 of your UILabel.

Comment: ok keep it like this... Leave out labels text everything.... I just want a white screen that is scrollable..how do i get that?

Comment: Add scrollview from storyboard to your main view in ViewController. and set scrollview size to fully cover main view .